# Styling issue with long table list

Tags: html, css

Here's my page:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq66n/)

when the table list is long, it is not extended within table. Need advise what's problem here :)

```
<table style='width:300px'>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>     
  <th>Points</th>
  <th>Points2</th>
  <th>Points3</th>
  <th>Points4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Specific height from `#main`

http://jsfiddle.net/Gq66n/3/

```
#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;    
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #39F;
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #333333;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0

}
table{margin-left:150px}
```

Comment: Hi, It's fixed the problem, however when i switched to another table format, the footer having issue: http://jsfiddle.net/SRBw5/ Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your `#main` has a `height: 700px`. Maybe you added it to make the height of the sidebar 700px but that is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You set your `#main` div to a specific pixel height (700PX), rather than letting it expand to include the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Gq66n/9/

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body { 
    height:100% 
}

#header {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 10px;
    background: #cc6600;
}
#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
#mainOutr{  display: table; width: 100%;}
#main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  height:100%; 
  display: table-row;
}
.tableHldr
{width: 80%;   background-color: #39F;   display: table-cell;}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: table-cell;


}

#sidebar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
}


#sidebar ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff9999;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #c3c3c3;
}

#footer {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #666600;
    padding: 20px;
}

#navigation {
    float: top;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    height: 30px;
}
#navigation ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #ffff99;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left:  1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}

#navigation li a:hover {background: #383}
```

This solves both the table expansion problem and the sidebar 100% height issues also.

Comment: Hi,
That fixed it, however it is still having problem blank space with footer when i switched to different table format: http://jsfiddle.net/C6q7J/

Please advise :)